使用予定が「Nginx、MySQL、Node.js、PHP」のとき、「Linux ディストリビューション」 のどこに着目して選べばよいか？
Linux ディストリビューション の違いについて教えて下さい。
いずれの ディストリビューションを選択しても、「Nginx、MySQL、Node.js、PHP」などは別途インストールが必要だと思うのですが、ディストリビューション毎の違いはなんですか？
ディストリビューションごとにサポートする対象や期間が異なるのですか？
長期的に一番安定しているものを選択したいのですが、どこに着目して選べばよいですか？
AI回答は下記のようになっていたのですが、

Ubuntu: シンプルで使いやすいディストリビューションで、初心者にもおすすめです。
Fedora: 最新のソフトウェアと技術を試すためのディストリビューションで、開発者向けです。
Debian: より安定性を重視し、長期サポートが提供されるディストリビューションです。

個人的には、
CentOSが、一番長期的に安定している、と思っていました。
Ubuntuは、Windowsに代わるホビー用途なのかと思っていました。
Fedoraは、最新技術をいち早く試してみたい方向けなので、長期安定化用途では不向きだと思っています。
Debianについては、全く分かりません。

「長期的に一番安定しているもの」と、別質問で出ている「より新しいバージョンのアプリ (パッケージ) を使いたい」は相反する要求です。何に重きを置くのかを整理する必要があります。

おそらく、あなたが本当に望んでいるモノは「EOLを気にせずにずっと使えるもの」だと思われます。前の質問でCentOS 7が既にEOLだと知ったあなた、CentOS 7の次のバージョンであったはずのCentOS 8も既にEOLになっているし、CentOS Streamというよくわからないものもあるし、そしてお勧めしないとか言われているし、という状態ではないかと思います。つまり、「バージョン」とか「ディストリビューション」とか、そういった組合せでEOLが変わるのを調べるのが面倒であるとか、どんな物でもしばらく使っているとサポート終了になることが不満であるとか、とにかくできるだけ長く同じ物をそのまま使いたい言うことではないでしょうか。そして、できるなら、「特定のライブラリ等が古いために使えない」と言うことがないように、そこそこ新しいバージョンが常に使えるようになりたいと言ったところでしょう。

上のような話だった場合、同じLinuxを入れ直すことなくずっと使いたいというのであれば、選択肢は二つです。

メジャーバージョンのアップグレードが簡単なディストリビューションを使用する。
ローリング・リリースのLniuxを使用する。

最初の1.の例としては、Ubuntu 22.04LTSはapt full-upgradeで24.04LTSへ(いくつか注意事項はありますが)簡単にアップグレードできます。UbuntuだけでなくDebianも同じ仕組みを持っています。しかし、ディストリビューションによっては手順が複雑だったりアップグレードをサポートしていないものもあるため、それらを避ければ良いでしょう。
次の2.の例としてはArch Linuxがあります。Arch Linuxにはディストリビューション自体にバージョンはありません。各パッケージ(カーネル、ライブラリ、アプリ等)は随時アップデートされており、常にほぼ最新版を使用できます。いつも最新版を使いたいという場合がいいでしょう。Arch Linux以外には盆栽Linuxと言われるGentooやopenSUSE LinuxのTumbleweed等があります。
ただ、どのディストリビューションを使っても、開発が終了したり、方針が変更されたりすることはありえるので、永遠に継続できることを保証するディストリビューションはありません。

最後に、上の話は「常に最新の物が使いたいけど、OSの再インストールとかはしたくない。」という話です。「何かのサービスを提供し、それを長期運用したい」という場合は、同じバージョンのアプリやライブラリ等を使いつづけるほうがいいという考えもあります。その場合は、それぞれのEOLを調べて、なるべく長くなる物にするしか無いでしょう。商用のもの中にはお金を払い続ける限り無期限にサポートするというのもありますが、サポート金額は年々値上がりするようになるため、現実的ではなりません。
各ディストリビューションのEOLはendoflife.data等で簡単に調べられます。

私自身もよく整理できていなかった、こちらの意図を汲み取った回答をいただき、ありがとうございました。回答を読んで、メジャーバージョンのアップグレードができるディストリビューションがあることを初めて知りました。

(正解が無さそうだし, 好みの問題な気もしますが)

ディストリビューション毎の違いはなんですか？
ディストリビューションごとにサポートする対象や期間が異なるのですか？

どういったことに重きを置くか, スタンスの違いがあるようです
大まかに分類すると, Arch系, Debian系, Ubuntu系, Red Hat系, Slackware系, SUSE Linux系 ... などがあります
例えば CentOSの元は Red Hat系であり, (Red Hat社は)IBM関連なので, 企業環境での安定性とか長期サポートを重視してそうです。ビジネス用途とか。
多少は選択の参考になるかもしれない情報
参考:

(wikipedia.org) Linuxディストリビューション
(wikipedia.org) Linuxディストリビューションの比較



長期的に一番安定しているものを選択したいのですが、どこに着目して選べばよいですか？

裏を返せば, なかなかバージョンアップしないディストリビューションかもしれないので,
最新の何かを使う場合は問題が出るかもしれず, そこは注意したほうがよいでしょう
List of Linux distributions の右側の図にタイムラインがあり, 幹にあたるディストリビューションは長期間安定してそうです。(右側の図は, 他のタブで開くなどして眺めてみてください)

Debianについては、全く分かりません。

Debianも, 幹にあたるディストリビューションの中の一つです
例えば ラズパイの Raspberry Pi OSは Debianベースなので, それなりユーザー数が多いかも知れないし, 比較的手軽に使えそうです

「好みの問題」。どこに着目して好き嫌いを判断しているのか、が分かれば参考になるかもしれないと思い質問しました。

限りなく買い物質問っぽいのですが誘導してしまった身として
商用つまり当該 Linux OS 自体が目的ではなくて、その上で動作している Web アプリケーション群が正しく動き続けてくれることが目的であるというなら断然 RHEL です。それも有償サポート契約を結んでしまいましょう。商売で使っている以上は動作することが当たり前です。いざ動かなくなったときにはオイラやあなたよりもっと詳しい人のサポートを受けることができ、最短時間で商売を再開できるってのはとても重要（おいしい）です。詳しい説明聞いても理解することが難しすぎるような「アレげ」なことは専門家に任せちゃえばよいのです。オイラやあなたから見て不可解なまでに高度な代物となってしまった商売道具を修理するのは専門家に任せて、ツールを使う側は末端顧客からのクレーム対応をするとか、そのほうが分業できてお互いに幸せになれます。
オイラのとこの部署で、以前にはオンプレミスで持ってたソースコードサーバーも今は AWS にほぼ移行してしまいました。サーバーハードウエアの故障で共有リポジトリが見えないなんてくだらない状況に、なんでオイラたち開発者が時間とられなきゃならないんですか？
その契約を維持するだけのお金出せないってことだと話は別。ですがオイラのこの発言ではそういうところまで突っ込まないことにします。

「商用つまり当該 Linux OS 自体が目的ではなくて、その上で動作している Web アプリケーション群が正しく動き続けてくれることが目的であるというなら … 有償サポート契約を結んでしまいましょう」。なるほど、そういう話になるわけですね。「オンプレミスで持ってたソースコードサーバーも今は AWS にほぼ移行してしまいました」。AWSは話題になるだけあって、やっぱりメリットがあるのですね。まあ、そんな経費は……
